# Qt vs Visual Studio for scientific computing

Tags: visual-studio, qt, scientific-computing

I am embedded programmer, and have no experience with desktop programming. In my project have to display and calculate no of physical parameter like pH, temp.

Please suggest me which way to go: Qt or Visual Studio?

Which is best suited for scientific computing?

I'm asking this because I am going to give lot of my time to learning these tools.

Last think, Any open source lib or tool like NI Measurement Stdio in QT or VS..

Comment: You're on the wrong track (and the wrong website, we don't do recommendation questions). Qt is a C++ toolkit. Visual Studio is an IDE and compiler (for various languages). I suggest you start by picking one or two languages that seem appropriate for your task (based on what other people do in that field).

Answer (score 20):

Qt Creator and Visual Studio are both IDEs.

MFC and Qt Libraries both have GUI libraries for C++.

C++ and C# are both programming languages that you can compare and decide on.

Qt Libraries can be used in Visual Studio, using the Qt VS Add-in...

So assuming you want to stick with C++ and you have heard good things about Qt, here are some resources to look into:

Here are some of the resources you should explore for scientific computing in C++.  This is not an exhaustive list, but it should get you going.

- http://partow.net/programming/exprtk/ ExprTK (easy math expression
  library)
- http://www.vtk.org/ Visualization Toolkit
- http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/22988 Scientific Plotting in
  Qt
- http://qwt.sourceforge.net/ QWT (Qt Plotting Library)
- http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-other (Qt Add-In for Visual
  Studio)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Last think, Any open source lib or tool like NI Measurement Stdio in QT or VS.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/ Can help with the more complex math operations.  Also if you are doing a lot of Matlab like stuff, you should try NumPy and SciPy in a Python environment.  Also just for stock UI elements that look like dials and gauges, try this search: https://www.google.com/search?q=qt+dials+and+gauges

Comment: Qt Charts is another option to look at, too.

Answer (score 2):

you should make your hands dirty by trying one of those you prefer.

In my opinion I prefer Qt for C++ programming. And Visual Studio just for C# applications.

one more thing Qt is available in Windows, Linux and Mac. But VS is just for Microsoft OSs.

Comment: One last thing, any support or free lib for  virtual instrument qt or vs.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Yes, I search about the NI measurement studio.Measurement studio can be use with VS.But it is very expensive and I searching for open source tool or lib.